# Error while importing a library in robot frame work ride

Tags: python, syntax-error

Receive the below error while installation in cmd prompt

I have downloaded and kept the file in the below path file
C:\AutoItLibrary-1.1_x64>

> C:\AutoItLibrary-1.1_x64>python setup.py install Don't think we need
>   to unregister the old one... %SYSTEMROOT%\system32\regsvr32.exe /S
>   C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\AutoItLibrary\lib\AutoItX3.dll`%SYSTEMROOT%\system32\regsvr32.exe
>   /S C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\AutoItLibrary\lib\AutoItX3.dll`
>   Traceback (most recent call last):   returned non-zero exit status 5
>   File "setup.py", line 70, in 
>       subprocess.check_call(cmd, shell=True)